# How to localize Django website

Tags: django, localization, multilingual

I have a website developed using Django. I want to offer language switcher option to translate the site to another language.
Is there any plugin (like Google Language Translate for WordPress Site) or some other way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 0):

There is [django-autotranslate](https://github.com/ankitpopli1891/django-autotranslate), which translates your `.po` files using google translate. It does, however, depend on you having meaningful `.po` files, which in turn result from the proper use of all of django's internationalization utilities, such as the `[upn]gettetxt` functions,  the `trans` and `blocktrans` tag.

You should read [the django documentation on internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/). But the sad truth is: Machine translation is not good enough yet. If you want quality translations (which you want in any serious project) you have to translate your stuff yourself or have professional translators do it.

Comment: My website uses Templates and JavaScript and already developed. I have gone through the document,  according to my understanding use of I18N requires lots of recode and rework. Is there not anyway like plugin or something?

Comment: None that I know of. However, good IDEs can provide some tools to autodiscover strings to wrap, like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/extracting-blocks-of-text-from-django-templates.html).